# How to bind a port from Host system in Docker where already a service is running to a docker containers port.

Tags: java, docker, microservices, consul, service-discovery

I'm very new to Consul and docker so please bear with me if my question seems to be vague.

I have multiple web services which run in their own docker containers. Now I want to use consul(by hashicorp) as the service discovery tool. Consul agent runs on port 8500 by default. Now I will be running Consul on the host system where all docker containers are running (because it being a service discovery tool I cannot have each container have its own consul) and docker service running in the docker container to interact with the 8500 port which is running on the host system.

Initially I assumed that using docker port forwarding (-p) would work but after trying it the below error is what I get

`docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint practical_lamarr (dd21827e00a3218f9e090986c09f875a82yurd04b76d8a2528f0bccb854e05a3): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:8500: bind: address already in use.`

Can anybody tell me how can the consul running on the host system port be bound to the containers port.

Comment: Are you running docker container inside a VM?

Comment: yes, its ubuntu

Comment: Please share how are you configuring docker containers to register on consul and if Consul agent is running as a docker service mapped with local host machine's 8500 port. Without such information it's difficult to reproduce any issue or come up with a solution.

Comment: ok, I will update the question..thanks....one more thing if you know consul can u please have a look at another problem which I'm facing  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45385958/cannot-connect-to-consul-hashicorp-which-is-running-in-vm-ware